# Как реализовать «плавную» смену блоков?

Tags: jquery, css

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать следующую вещь: есть страничка, на страничке контент и внутри него ссылка. При клике на ссылку, контент «уезжает» влево за экран, а на его место справа из-за экрана «въезжает» блок с новым контентом.

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В jquery есть такая функция animate() которая позволяет все делать плавно